# Open Distro for Elasticsearch: reset default admin password

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elasticsearch-opendistro

I'm new to open distro for elasticsearch and trying to run it on the Kubernetes cluster. After deploying the cluster, I need to change the password for `admin` user.

I went through this post - [default-password-reset](https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/default-password-reset/102)

I came to know that, to change the password I need to do the following steps:

- `exec` in one of the master nodes
- generate a hash for the new password using `/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/tools/hash.sh` script
- update `/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml` with the new hash
- run `/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/tools/securityadmin.sh` with parameters

Questions:

- Is there any way to set those (via `env` or `elasticsearch.yml`) during bootstrapping the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to recreate `internal_users.yml` file with the updated password hashes and mounted the file in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml` directory for database pods.

So, when the Elasticsearch nodes bootstrapped, it bootstrapped with the updated password for default users ( i.e. `admin` ).

I used [bcrypt go package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt) to generate password hash.

Answer (score 2):

docker exec -ti ELASTIC_MASTER bash

/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/tools/hash.sh

##enter pass

yum install nano

#replace generated hash with new one
nano /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml

#exec this command to take place
sh /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/tools/securityadmin.sh -cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/ -icl -nhnv -cacert config/root-ca.pem  -cert config/admin.pem -key config/admin-key.pem

Answer (score 0):

You can also execute below commands to obtain value of username, password from you kubernetes cluster:

```
kubectl get secret -n wazuh elastic-cred -o go-template='{{.data.username | base64decode}}'
kubectl get secret -n wazuh elastic-cred -o go-template='{{.data.password | base64decode}}'
```

Note: '-n wazuh' indicates the namespace, use what applies to you

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html